# minima of a function of a tuple

Tags: python, scipy

I have a data set as:

```
2.699994   -2541.184861   
2.749996   -2541.189717   
2.779995   -2541.190735   
2.789996   -2541.190777   
2.799993   -2541.190668   
2.829992   -2541.189523   
2.858996   -2541.187427
```

I know this fits to a polynomial e.g.: `f(x)=a+b*x+c*x^3`

I am need to get the minima of the function.

I googled around, and looks like scipy.optimize is what I am looking for, but can't understand how to give the data.
Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two steps: First find the parameters by fitting the function. I used curve_fit for this. And then minimze the function. i used minimize, but this could also be done analytically.

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

# data
xdata = sp.array([2.699994, 2.749996, 2.779995, 2.789996, 2.799993, 2.829992, 2.858996])
ydata = sp.array([-2541.184861, -2541.189717, -2541.190735, -2541.190777, -2541.190668, -2541.189523, -2541.187427])

# function to fit
def f(x, a, b, c):
return a + b*x + c*x**3

# fit the parameters a, b, c
popt, pcov = sp.optimize.curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata)
print('Parameters a, b, c are: {0}'.format(popt))

# minimize the function (could also be done analytically)
res = sp.optimize.minimize(lambda x: f(x, *popt), 2.8)
print('Function is minimized for {0}.'.format(float(res['x'])))

# plot data, fitted function and minimum

# function
x = sp.linspace(2.65, 2.9, 100)
y = f(x, *popt)
plt.plot(x, y)

# data
plt.scatter(xdata, ydata)

# minimum
plt.scatter(res['x'], f(res['x'], *popt), color = 'red', s = 80)
plt.show()
```

[image: data and fit]